# A recurrence relation where the next term is related by the sum of previous pair product terms

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, products

How can I go solving the recurrence relation $T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} T(i)T(n-i)$.

Base Case: $T(1) = 1$, $T(2) = 1$

First few terms look like so:

$T(3) = T(1)T(2) + T(2)T(1) = 1 + 1 = 2$

$T(4) = T(1)T(3) + T(2)T(2) + T(3)T(1) = 2 + 1 + 2 = 5$

$T(5) = 14$ $\hspace{1cm}$  $T(6) = 42$ $\hspace{1cm}$ $T(7) = 132$

First order difference where $\Delta T(i) = T(i+1) - T(i)$

$\Delta T(1) = 0$ $\hspace{1cm}$ $\Delta T(2) = 1$ $\hspace{1cm}$ $\Delta T(3) = 3$$\hspace{1cm}$ $\Delta T(4) = 9$

$\Delta T(5) = 28$ $\hspace{1cm}$$\Delta T(6) = 90$

First order differences seem to be growing roughly quicker than $3^n$, which may give a rough lower bound.

Is there a way to solve this relation exactly or produce a rough upper bound. Also after computationally playing with the relation it seems $4^n$ may be one such upper bound.

Comment: Hint: find a functional equation for $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T(n)z^n$ and solve it. You will get $T(n) = \frac{1}{2(2n-1)}\binom{2n}{n} = C(n-1)$ where $C(n) = \frac{1}{(n+1)}\binom{2n}{n}$ is the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Thanks achille, I really appreciate the help. This problem stumped me for the better part of the day.